# laravel validation for checkboxes

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

How can I **validate 'at least one of the two checkboxes in my form was checked'?** I know other ways but I want to know if there is a validation rule for this in laravel?

Comment: @André I think you missed the part ' I know other ways'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, i think this is what you looking for:

```
$rules = array(
    'checkbox1' => 'required_without:checkbox2', //require if checkbox2 miss
    'checkbox2' => 'required_without:checkbox1', //require if checkbox1 miss
);
```

So if the two checkboxes are missed, validator will fail.

> > **required_without:foo,bar,...**
> >     The field under validation must be present only when any of the other specified fields are not present.

[Doc](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-required-without)

Answer (score 1):

In `Laravel`, there is a way to require a check box field to be checked using [accepted](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-accepted) and what it does is that, the field under validation must be yes, on, or 1.

But you have different requirements and in this case you can add your custom `rule` using something like this:

```
// You may keep this code in your class before validation inside the method
Validator::extend('isOneChecked', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    return ($value || Input::has($parameters[0])) ? TRUE : FALSE;
});
```

Now you may use this `rule` for example, if one of your check box's name is `checkbox1` and other one is `checkbox2` then use something like this:

```
$rules = array (
    // other rules...
    'checkbox1' => 'isOneChecked:checkbox2',
);
```